# To execute multiple bash scripts in diff directories using one single bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I have multiple bash scripts to bounce Jboss instances in multiple directories. These scripts accepts arguments

start | stop | reload | status | restart.

```
 /opt/xyz/x/X_FE.sh 
 /opt/xyz/x/X_BE.sh
 /opt/xyz/y/Y_FE.sh
 /opt/xyz/y/Y_BE.sh
 /opt/xyz/z/Z_BE.sh
```

I wish to have a single bash script which accepts the same arguments and execute all the 5 scripts mentioned above.

```
/opt/singlescript.sh start ---- must execute all the 5 scripts with start argument.
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would look something like this. There are multiple ways to do this and this is just one way

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "invoking x/X_FE with $1"
sh /opt/xyz/x/X_FE.sh $1

echo "invoking x/X_BE with $1"
sh /opt/xyz/x/X_BE.sh $1

echo "invoking y/Y_FE with $1"
sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_FE.sh $1

echo "invoking x/Y_BE with $1"
sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_BE.sh $1

echo "invoking z/Z_FE with $1"
sh /opt/xyz/z/Z_BE.sh $1
```

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU Parallel it looks like:

```
parallel ::: /opt/xyz/x/X_FE.sh  /opt/xyz/x/X_BE.sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_FE.sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_BE.sh /opt/xyz/z/Z_BE.sh ::: start
parallel ::: /opt/xyz/x/X_FE.sh  /opt/xyz/x/X_BE.sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_FE.sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_BE.sh /opt/xyz/z/Z_BE.sh ::: stop
```

If they cannot be run in parallel add -j1:

```
parallel -j1 ::: /opt/xyz/x/X_FE.sh  /opt/xyz/x/X_BE.sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_FE.sh /opt/xyz/y/Y_BE.sh /opt/xyz/z/Z_BE.sh ::: start
```